# Expected dimensions of the vector or matrix of coefficients in OLS

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I have 100 samples. I fitted these samples in Linear regression with $\text{intercept} = 0$, The coefficients obtained after these data are fitted is $6 \times 6$ matrix with every column values in each row same. For e.g.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1\\
2&2&\cdots\\
3&\cdots\\
\vdots\\
6&6&6&6&6&6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This is basic linear algebra, are you familiar with any linear algebra?

Comment: You should research a little bit how exactly linear regeression works and what kind of equation is the resulting matrix to be used with

Comment: Target = x * Predictors . Target = [1 * 6 ] and Predictors = [1 * 6 ] . There are 100 Target and 100 Predictors. I wonder why x = [ 6 * 6 ]. I believe it should be [1 * 6 ] just like Targets and Predictors. Yes, I know Linear Algebra.

Comment: Error I get is 1*6 matrix as predicted.

Comment: Please clarify what is the model (and add the information in comments about targets and predictors into the question). Furthermore, what did you exactly do to obtain that matrix (such as, use some software)?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer is concordant with your question, and consider making the title of your question more generic, so that other people can benefit from it if they search something like "Expected dimensions of the matrix of coefficients in OLS".

Answer (score 1):

The model equation for OLS is $$\mathbf{\hat y}=\mathbf{A\hat\beta}$$.

(Presumably) you have six explanatory or independent variables with 100 observations each, forming part of your model matrix together with the first column of $1$'s for the intercept. The matrix multiplication with the estimated coefficients will give you the 100 predicted or fitted values of the dependent variable:

$\begin{matrix}
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\color{blue}{\bf x_1} &\color{blue}{\bf x_2} &\color{blue}{\bf x_3} &\color{blue}{\bf x_4} &\color{blue}{\bf x_5}  &\color{blue}{\bf x_6} 
\end{matrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1}&\cdots\\
\vdots\\
\color{red}{1}&\cdots&& \\
\vdots\\
\color{red}{1}&\cdots&\Large{\color{purple}{100\times7}}&&&&\cdots\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\color{red}{1}_{\color{red}{100}}&\cdots&&&&&\cdots
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\hat\beta_\color{red}o\\\hat\beta_1\\\hat\beta_3\\\hat\beta_4\\\hat\beta_5\\\hat\beta_\color{red}6
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\hat y_1\\\hat y_2\\\hat y_3\\\hat y_4\\\vdots\\\vdots\\\hat y_{98}\\\hat y_{99}\\\hat y_{\color{red}{100}}
\end{bmatrix}$

If this is the case you have $[\text{model matrix}][\text{coeff's}]=[100\times7][7\times 1]$ predicting the $[\hat y]=[100\times1]$.